# Pass value to nested sub queries display distinct row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having more problems with sql, do any other graduates get given a piece of paper each day and they have to work out how to solve 10 queries.

I can get the code below to return the data when hard coding the values, but what I need to do is pass the values of name and item to sub queries, I cannot use functions or views and display results per customer.

```
SELECT  
    c.Name AS 'A',
    c.Address AS 'B',
    sales2.MinPrice AS 'C',
    MAX(sales.TotalItemsSold) AS 'D'
FROM 
    ABC c, 
    (SELECT SUM(i.Qty) AS TotalItemsSold
     FROM DEF i
     INNER JOIN GHI o ON i.Orderno = o.OrderNo               
     WHERE o.Cust = 'name') sales, 
    (SELECT (Min(s.Price) * i.Qty) AS MinPrice
     FROM ABC c 
     INNER JOIN GHI o ON c.Name = o.Cust        
     INNER JOIN DEF i ON i.Orderno = o.OrderNo  
     INNER JOIN JKL s ON i.Item = s.Item
     WHERE i.Item = 'item' AND o.Cust = 'name'
     GROUP BY i.Qty) sales2
GROUP BY 
    c.Name, c.Address, Sales2.MinPrice
```

Comment: Investigate how to use `CROSS APPLY`.  I haven't looked at your query in detail *(It's a head ache to work out what a query Should do when all that is given is what it does do)*, but `CROSS APPLY` does allow passing of values down a chain of queries.

Comment: Please provide table structures, sample data, and expected output given that data. This will give the best chance that someone can help you and also saves those people a lot of time trying to guess what you're after. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged